# Deploying SIP servlet on Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, sip, jain-sip

I'm new to SIP Servlet development and I would like to know how to deploy my Sip servlet to my  Jboss server.
I can't seem to find how to do it by googling it. I see a lot of information on using mobicents but do I have to? 
Can't I just deploy directly like I would my HTTP servlets?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Also what is the exact difference between JAIN sip servlets and Sip servlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobicents provide Jboss and tomcat applications servers with additional modules which are required to deploy and run your sipservlet application

if you download and extract the jboss distribution you can see there are some modules call
sip-presence,sip-balancer , mobicents-media-server-1.0.3.GA.sar in deploy folder these are few and you will find a lot of additional modules/resources.

What you have to do is download the jboss from [here](http://www.mobicents.org/mss-downloads.html) and deploy your sipservlet war file as a normal web deployment.

Comment: Thanks! So I am not to deploy as a SAR file right but as WAR? Does this also mean I do not need a sip.xml but a regular web.xml will do?

Comment: as par as I know you required sip.xml and their you will configure your sipservlet configurations details . I have my application it self a war file and I still required sip.xml to point my sipservlet details.