# how to config jboss for sip servlet

Tags: java, jboss, sip, restcomm, mobicents-sip-servlets

I newly work on sip servlet and find RestComm as good sip servlet and now I want to know more about its word therefore I start to config jboss myself.

I found interesting and helpful thing in this journey like mobicents-dar.properties that is help to me understand main part of container work.

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348152/deploying-sip-servlet-on-jboss) answer and know it's hard work but it's so important to me knowing this section.

But I can't fully config jBoss for sip servlet container.
I do this :

first I find this two directory in module directory of RestComm jBoss and insert them in my original jBoss

```
mobicents
scannotation
```

then I find this three file in standalone/configuration directory copy them too

```
dars/mobicents-dar.properties
mss-sip-stack.properties
standalone-sip.xml
```

then start jboss whit this command

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-sip.xml
```

but when start jBoss connector on 5080 , .... not start (there is no log of them in consol but when start RestComm binary log like this)

this lines not seen in my original Jboss

```
    20:24:00,280 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.undertow.SipProtocolHandler] (MSC service thread 1-5) Sip Connector started on ip address: 127.0.0.1, port 5082, transport ws, useStun false, stunAddress null, stunPort : -1, useStaticAddress: false, staticServerAddress null, staticServerPort -1
    20:24:00,280 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.undertow.SipProtocolHandler] (MSC service thread 1-4) Sip Connector started on ip address: 127.0.0.1, port 5081, transport tls, useStun false, stunAddress null, stunPort : -1, useStaticAddress: false, staticServerAddress null, staticServerPort -1
    20:24:00,281 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.undertow.SipProtocolHandler] (MSC service thread 1-8) Sip Connector started on ip address: 127.0.0.1, port 5080, transport tcp, useStun false, stunAddress null, stunPort : -1, useStaticAddress: false, staticServerAddress null, staticServerPort -1
    20:24:00,281 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.undertow.SipProtocolHandler] (MSC service thread 1-3) Sip Connector started on ip address: 127.0.0.1, port 5080, transport udp, useStun false, stunAddress null, stunPort : -1, useStaticAddress: false, staticServerAddress null, staticServerPort -1
    20:24:00,282 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.undertow.SipProtocolHandler] (MSC service thread 1-7) Sip Connector started on ip address: 127.0.0.1, port 5083, transport wss, useS
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to rebuild it yourself when you can use a binary already integrated with JBoss ?

Comment: if you want a cluster with a some node and carefully management for load balancing you need that